# ngrx store - How to add a new object in the app state array and displaying in componenet.html

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-store

I'm using @ngrx/store in my app and I'm having trouble pushing a new object in the app state array and displaying in componenet.html

file.ts// below is my reducer and app state interface to hold notification array

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

//app state interface immutable array of notification 

export interface AppState {
  notifications: Array<Notification>;
}

export interface Notification {
  name: string;
  id:string
}

export const ACTIONS = {
  ADD_NOTIFICATION: 'ADD',
}

//custom action interface for send payload with action while dispatching action.

export interface CustomAction extends Action {
  type: string;
  payload?:Notification;
}

// my reducer to add Notification object to app state array.

export function notificationReducer(state: Array<Notification> = [], action: CustomAction): Array<IFreelancer> {
     switch (action.type) {
      case ACTIONS.ADD_NOTIFICATION:
      return  [...state, action.payload];
      default:
      return state;
  }
}

//NotificationShowComponent.ts to get data from  app store and display 


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState, Notification, ACTIONS } from '../file.ts';
import * as Rx from 'RxJS';

@Component({
  selector: ' app-NotificationShowComponen',
  templateUrl: './NotificationShowComponent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./NotificationShowComponent.css']
})
export class NotificationShowComponent implements OnInit {
  notifications: Rx.Observable<Array<Notification>>; //observable array of notification 

   constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.notifications = store.select('notifications');
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

//  *ngfor to display notification when new added to app state array  NotificationShowComponent.html

I am getting problem below in shownotification.html, even though reducer is adding a new object to the array, for loop is not executing, and notification.length also not showing incremented value.

```
<li class="treeview" *ngFor="let notification of (notifications|async)">
  <span>Hire <h1>{{notification.name}}</h1></span>
</li>

{{(notifications|async).length}} //not incrementing
```

Comment: Could you please provide code of the module where you have included the StoreModule and your reducers? Also where is the selector that gives you the notification out of your state? You really should have a look on their example. From what I see this is not the way you are supposed to do it.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/reducers/index.ts

Comment: than for reply @SamiAl90, below is my app module, where I am importing store module and reduce.

Comment: import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
 import {NotificationManager} from './notificationReducer';
 imports: [
     BrowserModule,
   StoreModule.forRoot({freelancersReducer})
   ]